# How attribute a restrition for a variable inside a function

Tags: functions, function-construction

I have a function like this way:

```
f[x_] := x + 2;

In[148]:= f[b + 2]

Out[148]= 4 + b
```

How to impose a condition that the variable `x` cannot depend on a specific variable `b` and so not calculate `f`.

Comment: You already know `Condition` and `FreeQ`. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Could you be clearer ? I didn't get your question

Comment: You might try something like: f[x_] := If[x =!= b, x + 2]; This would evaluate f[x] as x+2 unless x happens to equal b, in which case it remains unevaluated as f[b]. You could of course add something specific for the case when x was b.

Comment: Does `f[x_] /; FreeQ[x, b] := x + 2` do what you need?